# Simple examples of initial/terminal morphisms that aren’t limits/colimts

Tags: category-theory

The [wikipedia page on universal properties](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_property) defines initial and terminal morphisms, and then gives three examples: Tensor algebras, products, and limits/colimits.

However, products are an example of limits, and I don’t have a good intuition about tensor algebras. Another example that I’ve seen is that of initial/terminal object, but this is perhaps *too* simple for me to get a good intuition.

Are there basic examples of initial/terminal morphisms that simple and easy to understand, and are not limits/colimits and not just initial/terminal objects?

Comment: In the category where a terminal object is terminal it is a limit.

Comment: @Nex, I am not sure what you mean. What does it mean for the terminal object to be “terminal”?

Comment: I just mean that a terminal object is the limit of the empty diagram. So it is always a limit.

Comment: Not related to what I said before, just another example: Let $U$ be the functor that sends a monoid to its underlying set. The initial morphism from a set $X$ to $U$ is the map sending each $x$ in $X$ to the word $(x)$ in the monoid $F(X)$ of words on the set $X$. The identity in $F(X)$ is the empty word and multiplication is by concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

Every adjunction yields initial and terminal morphisms in the sense described in the page you linked. More precisely, given a functor $F : \mathsf C \to \mathsf D$

> $F$ admits a left adjoint if and only if there is an initial morphism from $X$ to $F$ for each $X\in\mathsf D$.
>
> $F$ admits a right adjoint if and only if there is an terminal morphism from $F$ to $X$ for each $X\in\mathsf D$.

So there is a plethora of examples that are not limits/colimits. Nex's example about free monoids in the comments is among them.